# Visual Studio 2017 código en letra blanca

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

¿alguien tendrá una idea de porque el visual ya no detecta los colores en el código?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya probe reinstalando VS, reseteando la configuración (tools>import export... reset), importando la configuración de otro VS 2015, instalando temas, y nada esto hasta el momento pasa con los web.config y los .aspx con los aspx.cs si colorea normal.

probado ...Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" no existe en la carpeta.

borrar carpeta C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Temp: Nada, sigue igual.

borrar contenido: %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\ Nada sigue igual.

borrar C:\Users\Allwyn\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0 Nada sigue igual.

Comment: ¿Has intentado reparar el visual studio?

Comment: habrás incluido el archivo fuente al proyecto

Comment: fredyfx, Gracias. Si traté de repararlo.
Carlos, si señor, no importa que proyecto abra es igual.

Comment: y decime que probaste cambiando el esquema de colores...

Comment: Si señor tambien probe cambiando los esquemas de oscuro a claro, también instalé otros temas. 
Opté por desistalar, borrar registros y volver a instalar desde 0 haber si esto lo soluciona.

Comment: Muchachos la podemos cerrar por favor, la solución fue reinstalar el VS, ni idea de que fue lo que causó el error o porqué, pero al desistalarlo e instalarlo 2 veces funcionó, la primera no funcionó.

Answer (score 1):

Ve al siguiente directorio:

```
%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\
```

Dentro de esa ubicación, seleccionas la versión del Visual Studio y te diriges a la carpeta `ComponentModelCache`:

```
<visual_studio_version_number>\ComponentModelCache
```

Cierra toda instancia del Visual Studio, luego de ello eliminas todo el contenido de esta carpeta (`ComponentModelCache`)

Abres Visual Studio y debería estar funcionando sin problemas.

Referencia: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33335712/3613462

Comment: no funcionó, sigue completamente igual, traté un par de veces por si acaso y no dió. ;(